# Why traceroute is still Used?

Tags: network, traceroute, network-discovery

currenty I'm  reading an article  about 'Paris traceroute' , as i understood The Classical Traceroute give inexact information about the path that a packet traverse , 'incorrect links , missed nodes '...

My question is why traceroute is still used by network administrators ?knowing the incorrect result that it can give.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traceroute doesn't give inexact information, it performs tests in a specific way and give some results based on the response it receives (or do not receive).

You have to know how to interpret the response, and for example that a given packet may take a path different than the path shown by a traceroute.

Additionally when you use traceroute in a network you control you know what the result should be, and can compare the actual result vs the expected one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

People use it because it is available everywhere and it works fine on simple networks. Yes it falls down in some complex networking scenarios and yes those running those complex networks need advanced tools but I belive those are a minority of users.

Most users aren't trying to do detailed debugging of complex networks, they are trying to determine whether a problem is in their local network or "out on the internet" and/or find where the problem is in a relatively simple network.